# How to select multiple values in an array in json using jq

Tags: json, select, jq

[image: sample json]Am using jq to get multiple responses from the JSON file using the below command.

```
.components| to_entries[]| "\(.key)- \(.value.status)"
```

which gives me below

Server2- UP

server1 - UP

Splunk- UP

Datameer - UP

Platfora - UP

diskSpace- Good

But I want to select only a few I tried giving in braces of  to_entries[] but it didn't work.

Expected output:

Server1 - UP

Splunk -UP

Platfora - UP

Is there any way to pick only a few values.
Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: First, please edit your question with a representative sample of the json. Second, what do you mean by "I want to select only a few"? From the sample json, what is your exact expected output?

Comment: Please, add the actual json; not an image. We can't work with images, only code.

Answer (score 0):

With the -r command-line option, the following transforms the given input to the desired output, and is perhaps close to what you're looking for:

```
.components
| to_entries[]
| select(.key == ("server1", "Splunk", "Platfora"))
| "\(.key)- \(.value.status)"
```

If the list of components is available as a JSON list, then you could modify the selection criterion accordingly, e.g. using `IN` (uppercase) or `index`.